# Drupal 6 tableselect - Retain checkbox values across pagination

Tags: forms, 6

In Drupal 6, I am using tableselect theme with PagerSelect to generate table with checkboxes and pagination. Any thoughts on how to retain checkbox values on pagination?
Because in the first page , i checked 2 checkbox and go to the second page and check other checkbox

When i go back to the first page , the checked checkbox are lost

How can i fix it ?

here is how i do this using a method that  not follow the drupal standard coding like this

```
function mymodule_form(){
    global $base_url;
     drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.js', 'core', 'header');
     print drupal_get_js(); 
     $url = $base_url.'/'.arg(1);

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chkArray = new Array;
            var someGlobalArray = new Array;
            var hrefs = [];
            var burl = "<?php echo $base_url.'/'.arg(1); ?>";
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('li.pager-item').find("a").each(function(){
                        hrefs.push($(this).attr('href'));
                    });

                    $(".form-checkbox").click(function() {
                        someGlobalArray=[];
                        $('.form-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                            someGlobalArray.push($(this).val());
                        });
                        console.log(someGlobalArray);
                        i = 0;
                        $('li.pager-item').find("a").each(function(){
                            //h = $(this).attr('href');
                            h = hrefs[i] + "&ids[]=" + someGlobalArray.join(",");
                            $(this).attr('href', h);
                            //someGlobalArray = [];
                            i++;
                        });
                    });
            });
        </script>



     $form = array(); 
     $tableHeader = array(
        'test' => array('field' => 'n.title', 'data' => 'test'),
        'test1' => array('field' => 'l.name', 'data' => 'test1'),
        'test2' => array('field' => 'l.postal_code', 'data' => 'test2'),
        'test3' => array('field' => 'l.city', 'data' => 'test3'),
        'test4' => array('field' => 'cttc.field_activite_nid', 'data' => 'test4'),
        'test5' => array('field' => 'cttc.field_gestionnaire_value', 'data' => 'test5'),
     );
    $query = "SELECT nid FROM  table  ";
    // Pass the sql to the tablesort_sql here
    $query .= tablesort_sql($tableHeader);

   $result = pager_query($query,250,0,$sql_count);  

   while ($row =db_fetch_object($result)) {
         $nid_list[] = $row->nid;
   }

    foreach($nid_list as $val){
         $node = node_load($val);
         //print "<pre>";print_r($node);
         $options[$node->nid] = array(
             'test' => $node->title,
             'test1' => $node->location['street'],
             'test2' => $node->location['postal_code'],
             'test3' => $node->location['city'],
             'test4' => $tmp_activite[$node->field_activite[0]['nid']],
             'test4' => $node->field_gestionnaire[0]['value'],
         );
    }     
    if (!empty($options)) {
            $ids = isset($_GET["ids"]) ? $_GET["ids"] : array();
            $tab_check = array();
            global $tab_check;
            foreach($ids as $v) {
                //print_r($ids);
                $tids = explode(",", $v);
                foreach($tids as $id) {
                    $tab_check[$id] = TRUE;
                }
            }
            //print "<pre>";print_r($tab_check);
            if(arg(2)!=""){
                $form['nodes'] = array(
                  '#type' => 'tableselect',
                  '#header' => $tableHeader,
                  '#options' => $options,
                  '#default_value' => $tab_check,
                  '#multiple' => TRUE,
                  '#advanced_select' => TRUE,
                );
            }else{
                $form['nodes'] = array(
                  '#type' => 'tableselect',
                  '#header' => $tableHeader,
                  '#options' => $options,
                   '#default_value' => $tab_check,
                   '#multiple' => TRUE,
                  '#advanced_select' => TRUE,
                );
            }
            $form['pager'] = array('#value' => theme('pager', NULL, 250, 0));
    }
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
     $ids_del = isset($_GET["ids"]) ? $_GET["ids"] : array();
            $tab_check_del = array();
            foreach($ids_del as $v) {
                $tids_del = explode(",", $v);
                foreach($tids_del as $id) {
                    $tab_check_del[] = $id;
                }
            } 

     if(sizeof(tab_check_del)>0){
      foreach($tab_check_del as $val){
        $query = "DELETE from mytable WHERE nid ='".$val."' ";
        db_query($query);
      }

}
```